# Unity launcher: combine click and modifier key (Shift, Alt, Ctrl, ...)

Tags: keyboard, launcher, configuration

In Unity launcher (icons on left side), is it possible to configure a `.desktop` file to, for instance, run something else if <kbd>Control</kbd> is pressed.

For instance, Gimp below

[image]

The file `gimp.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications` shows (excerpt)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=GIMP Image Editor
GenericName=Image Editor
Comment=Create images and edit photographs
Exec=gimp-2.8 %U
TryExec=gimp-2.8
Icon=gimp
Terminal=false
```

A click on the icon runs `gimp-2.8 %U`.

Is there a way to add some configuration to that file in order for a <kbd>Control</kbd>-**click** (for instance) to run another command, `gimp-2.8 --no-cpu-accel %U` for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. You could do something close, though, adding an option to the quicklist menu shown in your screenshot. Just add something like this to the very end of your `gimp.desktop` file, and save the result in `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
Actions=Noaccel;

[Desktop Action Noaccel]
Exec=gimp-2.8 --no-cpu-accel %U
Name=Launch Without Acceleration
```

(Caveat: I haven't tested this myself yet.)

Source: http://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#extra-actions